# How do I add router-link to a button click function on Angular 8?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to add a routing function to a button on angular . I have added a (click) function to the button but how do I implement the function to navigate on the home.ts component ?

```
<button class="navbut" (click)="redirect()"> INVEST NOW</button >
```

Comment: I suggest you read the official guide about routing: https://angular.io/guide/router#navigating-back-to-the-list-component. In the example, you will need to inject Router of course.

Comment: @wizdemonizer Provide the answer in answer question and not in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed , I declared a router and imported it from @Angular/router then write the redirect() function in my ts file :

```
import {Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
constructor( private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
}


redirect() {
    this.router.navigate (['/investment']);
  }
```